# NSLookup how to interpret output

Tags: linux, command-line, networking

Hi can someone help me to understand what this NSLOOKUP command's output

```
[x]$ nslookup sample.abc.com
Server:         161.43.32.162
Address:        161.43.32.162#53<-- ???

Name:   sample.abc.com
Address: 161.43.30.72
```

In the address part one with arrow pointing question mark. What does the hash before 53 stands for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hash is a separator between the IP of the server that replied to your request, and the port it's service was running on.

You got your reply from the server `161.43.32.162` and it's DNS service was running on port `53`. The `#` separates the two values.